# What does the "-c" mean in an ant exec task?

Tags: ant

These are two ant tasks:

```
 <target name="hg.add" >
    <exec dir="." executable="hg">
        <arg line="add ${reports-summary}" />
    </exec>
</target>


<target name="hg.add">
      <exec executable="/bin/sh">
            <arg value="-c"/>
            <arg value="hg add ${reports-summary}"/>
      </exec>
</target>
```

This two tasks seem to have the same function. But why the second one needs to write"/bin/sh" and "-c"?

Answer (score 2):

The -c is just an argument to the executable it does not mean anything special to the ant exec task.

The first target is running the `hg` executable directly.

The second target is running the Linux/Unix shell command (`/bin/sh`) and passing it the `-c` argument which tells the shell to execute a command given in the next argument. So this will run the same command as the first target, but the shell command may set up things like environment variables before running the command.